# How to return the array list of number has sum equal to the given number

Tags: c++

I am practicing in C++ about array. I am doing Sum of numbers in an array equal to the given number. I have code like this

```
bool hasArrayTwoCandidates(int arr[], int arr_size,
                       int sum)
{
    int l, r;
 
    /* Sort the elements */
    sort(arr, arr + arr_size);
 
    /* Now look for the two candidates in 
       the sorted array*/
    l = 0;
    r = arr_size - 1;
    while (l < r) {
        if (arr[l] + arr[r] == sum)
            return 1;
        else if (arr[l] + arr[r] < sum)
            l++;
        else // A[i] + A[j] > sum
            r--;
    }
    return arr[l];
}
 
/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 4, 45, 6, 10, -8 };
    int n = 16;
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
 
    // Function calling
    cout<<hasArrayTwoCandidates(arr, arr_size, n);
 
    return 0;
}
```

That's just displaying the text, I would like to show all the numbers in the array has given to know that what are the numbers in the array equal to the given number.

**Example:**

This is an array already declear:
**int arr[] = { 1, 4, 45, 6, 10, -8 };**

And the output should be like this:
**List of number equal 16 is: 6, 10**

How can I return that number, please help me with this, thank you so much

Comment: Since you're using C++ you should really take advantage of things like `std::vector` so you don't have to pass through the array length separately. It also eliminates the need for clunky calculations like `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`.

Comment: `hasArrayTwoCandidates` returns a `bool`, which would presumably indicate whether it's possible to sum two elements of `arr` to a total of `sum`. The actual return statement `return arr[l];` doesn't... Really seem to do anything like that, though. Take a close look at what exactly the state of `l` and `r` are after your loop has finished, decide what you want to return (a bool? a pair of ints? some kind of `std::optional` construction?), and then return that.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, you're right. Exactly I would like to return the list of numbers in an array that the sum of these numbers is equal to the given number. That means I want to return **Int**. Could you help me with the next step, please?

Comment: Well, remember that a return type of `int` is a _single_ `int`. If you want to return more than one, you'd be looking at something like a `std::pair<int, int>` for your return type. You may find [std::make_pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) relevant.

Comment: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` You can use `std::size(arr)` instead.

Comment: you should also check every possible combinattion by using two for loops and iterating throught the array and iterate for every element throught the array again

Comment: do not use raw array, use std::vector instead

Answer (score 0):

> You just need to store the values which results sum in some external vector of pair.
>
> Also I've modify your function a bit.

> ### Code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
    
vector<pair<long long,long long>> ans;    /* ans array for holding answer's pair values */
    

bool hasArrayTwoCandidates(vector<long long> &a,long long sum){
     bool flag=0;  // Tracks if the sum pairs exists or not 
     
     // sorting the array 
     
     sort(a.begin(),a.end());
     
     long long l=0,r=a.size()-1;
     
     while(l<r){
         long long p=a[l]+a[r];
         
         if(p==sum){
             flag=1;
             ans.push_back(make_pair(a[l],a[r]));
             l++;
             r--;
         }
         else{
             if(p<sum)
             l++;
             
             else
             if(p>sum)
             r--;
         }
     }
     
     return flag;
  
}

 
/* Driver program to test above function */

int main(){
    
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    
    vector<long long> a{ 1, 4, 45, 6, 10, -8 };      /* Input array */
    long long sum=16;   

  
    if(hasArrayTwoCandidates(a,sum)){
        cout<<"List of number equal to "<<sum<<" is : \n";
        for(long long i=0;i<ans.size();i++){
            cout<<ans[i].first<<" , "<<ans[i].second<<"\n";
        }
    }
    else
    cout<<"There are no such pairs";
 
}
```